# iOS 9.0.2 Safari - Cannot open the page. Protocol error. - On form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, forms, safari

I am starting to get some users reporting that they are unable to submit a form on my website.

This only seems to be affecting users who have upgraded to iOS 9.0.2 and are trying to submit the form using Safari.

They receive the following message upon clicking the submit button:

Safari cannot open the page.

The error was: "The operation couldn't be completed. Protocol error".

The form works fine on older iOS versions and in all other browsers...